# Creating HTML select drop down list with sequential option value via Javascript loop

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying create a drop down list of items under a select tag. I'd rather code that in JavaScript than coding the option tag one item at a time. There are several items in the list. Each of them has its own name and mark sequentially with help of for loop. All of the items must be in one select tag. The first selection by default is car1 which will appear at first of the list by default and the onchange will accept that value by default.

```
   <select name="choice" onchange="myFunction(this.value)">
    options = "<option value='B1'>Boat1</option>";
        for (var i=1; i<=10; i++) {
            options += "<option value='"'B' + i"'>" + 'Boat'+ i +"</option>";
            }
     document.getElementById('mapchoice').appendChild = options;

    options = "<option value='J1'>Jet1</option>";
        for (var i=1; i<=10; i++) {
            options += "<option value='"'J' + i"'>" + 'Jet'+ i +"</option>";
            }
     document.getElementById('mapchoice').appendChild = options;

        options = "<option value='T1'>Truck1</option>";
        for (var i=1; i<=10; i++) {
            options += "<option value='"'T' + i"'>" + 'Boat'+ i +"</option>";
            }
     document.getElementById('mapchoice').appendChild = options;
```

The display should look like in the list of drop down from top to bottom like car1, car2, car3, ..., jet1, jet2, jet3, ..., truck1, truck2, truck3, ..

I'm lost on this one. Helpful detailed advice and solutions would be appreciated from a novice.

Comment: You are mixing up script [JS] and HTML part together ! and it tageted to 'mapchoice' id which is not present.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues with your script:

1. If you want to use appendChild you have to pass a Node element, check this link for details: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp
2. You don't have to use appendChild if you want to build the HTML as a string, I'd use innerHTML: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp
3. Your `<options>` tag doesn't have an id, and in your javascript you're looking for an object by the id of `mapchoice`
4. If you're going to pass a string and use double quotes to mark the beginning and the end of the string then don't use double quotes in the middle or use an escape character (i.e. `options += "<option value='"'B' + i"'>" + 'Boat'+ i +"</option>";` is not going to work because of the double quotes before the `'B'`, what you're after is `options += "<option value='\"'B' + i\"'>" + 'Boat'+ i +"</option>";`

Here's a working fiddle that does what you're after: https://jsfiddle.net/bsoLmbk1/

HTML:

```
<select id="choice" name="choice" onchange="myFunction(this.value)">
    <option value="default">Default</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
options = "";
for (var i=1; i<=10; i++) {
  options += "<option value='\"'B' + i\"'>" + 'Boat'+ i +"</option>";
}

document.getElementById('choice').innerHTML = options;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```js
var select = document.getElementById("mapchoice");
     
//loop first list
for (var i = 1; i<=10; i++)
{
   var opt = document.createElement('option');
   opt.value = "car" + i;
   opt.innerHTML = "Car" + i;
   select.appendChild(opt);
}

//loop second list
for (var i = 1; i<=10; i++)
{
  var opt = document.createElement('option');
  opt.value = "jet" + i;
  opt.innerHTML = "Jet" + i;
  select.appendChild(opt);
}
//continue loop
```

```html
<select id="mapchoice" onchange="myFunction(this.value)"></slect>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to build the `option`, Call that function with the two parameters

```js
function createOptions(optionName, times) {
  for (var x = 0; x <= times; x++) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = optionName + x;
    option.innerHTML = optionName + x;
    document.getElementById('selectOption').appendChild(option)

  }
}

var _boats = createOptions('Boat', 5);
var _jets = createOptions('Jet', 5);
var _trucks = createOptions('Truck', 5);


function myFunction(elem) {
  console.log(elem.value)

}
```

```html
<select name="choice" onchange="myFunction(this)" id="selectOption"></select>
```